# Rails: Paperclip gem no longer works after switching computers

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I switched from a Sony computer to an Asus, downloaded the same programs as I had on the Sony and cloned my Rails 4.0.10 project from Bitbucket. Everything else behaves the same, but Paperclip has inexplicably stopped working, though the two development environments should be exactly the same. I used Paperclip to add an avatar to my User model, but now User.create fails when I attach an avatar. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling it, but that made no difference. Does anyone with Paperclip experience know what might have happened?

Gemfile:

```
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
# ...
```

models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "500x500", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "50x50!" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  # ...
```

controllers/users.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # ...
    if @user.save
      render :action => "crop"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Failed"
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
    end
```

views/users/new.html.erb

```
  <%= form_for @user, :url => users_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name" %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :display_picture %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

views/users/crop.html.erb

```
<% content_for(:head) do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.Jcrop" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Jcrop.min" %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
ready = $(function() {
  $("#cropbox").Jcrop();
});
</script>
<% end %>

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);

<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:large), :id => "cropbox" %>
```

Comment: Do you have ImageMagick installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure imagemagick is installed on your machine.  This isn't something 'bundle install' will cover.

Follow the instructions here

http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php

Or use homebrew or other package managers

Comment: You're right, I needed to install imagemagick. But now image_tag @thing.avatar.url(:size) just displays the name of the image, not the image itself. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: try @thing.avatar.image_url(:size)

Comment: That returns "undefined method `image_url' for #<Paperclip::Attachment:0x00000004e0e558>"

Comment: Sorry, try @thing.avatar_url

Comment: Hm, that returns "undefined method avatar_url".

Comment: It's definitely a problem with paperclip, because image_tag "some_other_image.jpg" returns the image just fine.

Comment: When you upload the avatar, does it save :rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:style there

Comment: It saves under :rails_root/public/system/users/avatars/000/000.

Comment: So it saves... Ok. Do you have the line in the model :has_attached avatar?

Comment: I have "has_attached_file :avatar,..."

Comment: Yeah that's what you need... try image_tag(@thing.avatar_url(:size))